# I can't reach a variable in a nested while loop

Tags: python, loops, while-loop

Here is the problem, it's just a simple program that rolls the dice, but when I write "no" in (want), the loop continues.

```
import random

play_continue = True
want = ""
want_play = False
while play_continue:
    while not want_play:
        try:
            want = input("Do you want to play?: ")
        except:
            print("I don't understand what you said")
        else:
            if want == "no":
                play_continue = False
            elif want == "yes":
                want_play = True
            else:
                print("I don't  understand")
```

Comment: Why do you have two nested while-loops? One is enough. What's tripping you up right now is the fact that setting `play_continue` to false is not enough to get you out of the inner while-loop, since that one is interested in `want_play`.

Comment: Just use one variable and set it either to `True` or `False`.

Answer (score 0):

the reason is that you are still on the first step of the toplevel while loop, since the inner one is ongoing, even though you changed the value of `play_continue` the check never happens because the program never gets back around to it as the inner loop has yet to finish.

you can think of the whole inner loop as a single instruction such as

```
while play_continue:
    do_stuff()
```

the `play_continue` condition is only checked once `do_stuff()` is completed, which in your case it is not